# How to use ref in React Navigation header

Tags: javascript, react-native, reference, react-navigation, react-ref

I'm adding a search bar with button (i.e. search icon) in navigationOptions of React navigation. Now I want to send the typed text with `navigate` function. I don't know how to pass reference of TextInput to get its native text. Following is the code I've done so far.

```javascript
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => (
    headerStyle: {
        ...
    },
    headerTitle: (
        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: 75, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 50, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <TextInput style={{ width: '85%', padding: 15 }}
            onSubmitEditing={
                (e) => (e.nativeEvent.text.length > 2) && navigation.navigate('Brands', {text: e.nativeEvent.text})
            } />

            <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: '15%', padding: 15 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Brands'/*, {text: HERE I WANT TO GET TEXT FROM REFERENCE}*/)}>
                <Icon type='FontAwesome' name='search'
                style={{ color: 'red', 20, textAlign: 'center' }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
)};
```

But as `navigationOptions` is static, I can't use `this` keyword inside it. Also I can't use `state` inside navigationOptions as well. So how could I use `ref` to get input text on button press.

---

**EDIT**

I want to get `TextInput` value from `ref`

```
<TextInput ref={(ref) => { this.input = ref; }} />
// OR
<TextInput ref='input' />
```

So that I can get its value from

```
this.input._lastNativeText
// OR
this.refs['input']._lastNativeText
```

But I cant use `this` keyword or `state` in `navigationOptions` because its static. How can I access the value of TextInput on button click?

Answer (score 0):

send callback to navigationOptions through naviagtion prop .
set callback value in componentDidMount

```
  componentDidMount=()=> {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
          onSubmitEditing: this.onSubmitEditing,
        });
    }

    onSubmitEditing=(event)=>{
        console.log(event);
        //this is avaialbel here  
      }
```

Get on SubmitEdit function from naviagttion params

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation = this.props.navigation }) => {
    const onSubmitEditing = navigation.state.params.onSubmitEditing;
    return {
      headerTitle: (
        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: 75, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 50, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
          <TextInput style={{ width: '85%', padding: 15 }}
            onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing} />

          <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: '15%', padding: 15 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Brands'/*, {text: HERE I WANT TO GET TEXT FROM REFERENCE}*/)}>
            <Icon type='FontAwesome' name='search'
              style={{ color: 'red', size: 20, textAlign: 'center' }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think you didn't get me. I'm talking about `ref` as either `<TextInput ref={ref => this.input=ref}>` OR `<TextInput ref='input'>` to get the value from **TextInput** with `this.input._lastNativeText` OR `this.refs['input']._lastNativeText` respectively. But I cant use `this` keyword in `navigationOptions` because its static

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody needs this

```
   componentDidMount(){
    ---
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
          setMenuRef: this.setMenuRef.bind(this),
        });
    ---
    }
    
    _menu = null;

    setMenuRef = ref => {
        this._menu = ref;
      };
    
    onSortClick() {
        this._menu.show();
      }
    
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}){
    
    headerRight:(
    ---
    ref={navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.setMenuRef}
    ---
    )
    
    }
```